# OpsView/Nagios SNMP USB device monitoring

Tags: usb, monitoring, snmp, nagios, opsview

Is there any way to monitor USB devices, connected to the server in Opsview Core?
Or there is any software that I can install to make SNMP possible for USB devices?

Some of the USB security dongles often disconnects by themselves. The point is to have notifications when they lost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your USB dongles are connected to the Opsview Server, and if this server is running Linux (i don't know much about Opsview except that it can use nagios plugins), it would probably need only a few lines of code to write a plugin that parses `/proc/bus/usb/devices` or the output of `lsusb` and checks for the vendor id / product id / product name of the USB dongles.

Comment: Unfortunately, devices are connected to another server (running Windows)

Comment: Then the presence of the USB dongle is probably indicated by some key in \\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\usb*, which you can check if you install nsclient++ on the windows machine and use CheckSingleRegEntry on it (not documented well, but i found this: http://nsclient.org/nscp/discussion/message/2996#2996)